# Android Project Not Create

Tags: android

I've been developing some applications in android using eclipse IDE.

Android project not create.

In the error show[image]

Comment: Choose a theme as that is where the error seems to come from.

Comment: I am theme selected and compile with: drop down no data found

Comment: You need to choose Compile with and Theme.

Comment: It is recommended to use Android Studio as it is the supported IDE.

Comment: Yes i agree but compile with: dropdown is blank

Comment: You have a warning on the package name - is it possible that you already created a package with the same name ?

Comment: Download Api14(Jellybean) and Api 20(KitKat) SDK in Eclipse then restart the eclipse then create new project

Answer (score 0):

Update ADT plugin and then SDK tools and after when you will try to create a new project, the error will not occur.